# SSRS Row Comparing and highlighting differences

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm using the following iif statement to compare 2 different rows using the conditional format to change the color to Red if the field is different.  I've been using this method on the same report and some fields it works and some fields it doesn't work.

```
   =iif(instr(Fields!Prev_AltAcctTypeB.Value, Fields!After_AltAcctTypeB.Value)>0,"Transparent",'Red")
```

Is there a different way to display the differences in fields or a trick to correct this?  As you can see from this picture below, there's no differences yet it shows the conditional format as being different.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying many different ways to make this work.

Remove the `Instr` and add single prens around each of the fields, and remove the >0.  This seems to work great.

```
=iif((Fields!Prev_AltAcctTypeB.Value) = (Fields!After_AltAcctTypeB.Value),"Transparent",'Red")
```